# Fancybox not loading SWF in lightbox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

http://kevin-plunkett.com/beta/index.html

While images are loading fine, the SWF and iFrames (in the advertising section) are loading in the full browser window. Did I leave something out that enables SWF and iFrame support in Fancybox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the swf is working ... in the case of iframes

this class

```
class="fancybox.iframe"
```

should be

```
class="fancybox fancybox.iframe"
```

because the selector "`fancybox`" is the one bound to fancybox while "`fancybox.iframe`" sets the type of content.